# Use two different reduce functions in Mapreduce

Tags: java, mapreduce, reduce

I would like to use two different reduce functions in a mapreduce program, 
each with it's own signature.
the signature different is in the different key-objects it expects. 
Can it be done?
How?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're trying to do.  Do you mean multiple reducers in a single `Job`?  If so, the closest you're going to get is probably something like a `ChainReducer`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MultipleOutputs class and a single reducer.  You still have to define output key/value types and an output format for the reducer, but you configure the two outputs (with differing types) via calls to static methods in the MultipleOutputs class.  You then construct a MultipleOutputs instance in your reducer and use that instance to write your key/value pairs.  The javadoc has fairly useful examples.